# IE8 focus on newly opened tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

in IE8 i have this problem that when a new tab is opened through a link using `target="_blank"`, the view doesn't switch to newly opened tab. i know you can do it through the settings panel, but we can't ask the users of our site to do it. is there a jQuery sample/ example which can be helpful?

Comment: would you please submit your working code?

Comment: no specific javascript/ jquery code, plain html link tag... want to know how can this be achieved through JS?

Answer (score 0):

Would window.blur() that removes the focus of current page help you?

Comment: @user2060549 in theory you need to have focus somewhere if you remove form current, then maybe it will automatically get to newone